# Reflecting the component from a kit assembly on the finished item

Tags: acumatica

My business logic is specialized such that for a given class of Stock Item, we always have a single component with a Default Component Qty of 1 in the Kit Specification.

We do list alternate raw parts in the Kit Specification, with a Default Component Qty of 0. [Kit Spec screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kM3VV.png)

I'm looking to reflect the both the component name and one or more fields from the component part on the record for the related stock item finished good.

Can I do this with a PXFormula and Search combination? I tried without success to do this kind of lookup; I'm getting a 0 in my raw part field.  (Also, would love to display the InventoryCD of the component rather than the InventoryID.)

```
**        #region UsrRawPart
    [PXDBInt()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Raw Part", Enabled = false)]
    [PXFormula(typeof(Search<INKitSpecStkDet.compInventoryID, Where<INKitSpecStkDet.dfltCompQty, Equal<decimal1>, And<INKitSpecStkDet.kitInventoryID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>, And<INKitSpecStkDet.revisionID, Equal<int1>>>>>))]        
    public virtual Int32? UsrRawPart { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrRawPart : IBqlField { }
    #endregion**
```

Do I need to create formula fields to aggregate the component item back up to the finished good item instead?

Is there some other approach altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per offline discussion with Ruslan, a formula field is not designed to go cross-object like this.  I will be overriding the Persist method on the Kit Spec and calling the business logic controller to make updates to the finished product stock item.

Answer (score 0):

The `PXFormulaAttribute` only subscribes to **RowSelecting** handler when attached to an unbound field. For a bound field, `PXFormula` won't do anything when used with `Search` operator.

When do you expect the framework to execute your `Search` statement? If when the record is inserted in `PXCache`, the `PXDefaultAttribute` will get you there.

To display the InventoryCD of the component rather than the InventoryID, you should decorate the field with the `InventoryAttribute` or some other `PXDimensionSelectorAttribute` of the **INVENTORY** dimension and SubstituteKey set to `InventoryItem.inventoryCD`

Comment: Thank you!  I would like it to be executed on initial insert and also if the component item on the kit spec with a qty of 1 changes.

Comment: Not sure that I understand what "if the component item on the kit spec with a qty of 1 changes" means... Would be very helpful if you provide couple screenshots explaining requirements in greater details.

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot (in the original question description) of the Kit Spec with both the standard component (default qty 1) and the alternate component (default qty 0).  I'm looking to show the standard component dynamically on the finished product stock item.